# how to create dynamic call to ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I create a call to editClient from showClientList function that is created by ng-click event

```
$scope.showClientList=function(){

....
            $('<input/>').attr({
                type: 'button',
                id: 'editClient',
                value: 'Edit Client'
            }).appendTo(td).on('ng-click', editClient($scope.data.clients[i]));
            td.appendTo(tr);
            tr.appendTo(table);
}

$scope.editClient=function(client){
....
}
```

Comment: `ng-click` isn't an event, but an attribute

Comment: You should not perform DOM manipulation from your controllers, consider refactoring it to a more angular way, like binding the clients list on your template using ng-repeat, put there your ng-click and it will work.

Comment: What you're doing is a jQuery style of doing things. With angular you should not manipulate DOM in your controller but use a directive with bound events instead

Comment: You should not be using JQuery to create elements. Create a directive, then you can register your `ng-click` with handler easily. EDIT: @IgorMalyk Beat me to it